# How to make hyperlinks in bibliography without showing URL

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, color, natbib

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref} % For hyperlinks in the PDF
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{plain}

\section{Introduction}

Citation~\cite{Gubbay1990} 

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{bib.bib}

\end{document}
```

I would like to make the whole reference author, title, journal etc. (except the numbering eg [1]) a hyperlink, which is specified in the .bib file as url = {} without showing the URL. This would mean you could click anywhere on the reference and it would take you to the URL you wrote in the .bib file. The entire reference would appear blue in my example if this is possible.

Comment: Have you looked into the `href` macro in `hyperref`?

Comment: No, I haven't. How do you do that?

Comment: look at [the manual](ftp://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf). I think it's as simple as `\href{link}{anchor}`

Comment: If I put that after \begin{document} it doesn't work.

Comment: the following works for me: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue}
\begin{document}
\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com}{SE}
\end{document}`

Comment: the `\href` command is part of the solution, but not really the problem here, because inserting it into the bibliography is a non-trivial task, because you have to wrap the whole content of the entry in the anchor-argument.